# Gitlab runner runs till timeout when doing request to aws lambda

Tags: java, kubernetes, aws-lambda, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a code fragment when I do HTTP request to aws labda .Everything works fine on local machine or somewhere else.When I want to run it on gitlab kubernetes runner it get stuck on that line of code till timeout.

```
URL obj = new URL("https://x-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my/endpoint");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

I don't get any errors.On aws part everything is working fine.
It's pure http request so I don't think I need additional installations on runner part.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you try SSHing into the runner and trying to `curl` the endpoint, ping the host or even tracerouting the host? There’s a possibility this is a network or firewall issue, either on AWS’s or Gitlab’s site (including the environment of the custom runner, if you’re using one).

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Thank you for your response.I have tried and everything is working fine when I curl to endpoint from my custom runner side.But when pipeline is running it get stuck .It seems to me like connection is always open and cannot be closed,but when I look to AWS part it has returned response as expected.